# Question mark '?' given in arguments of a method

Tags: c#

I have a code containing a class with the following method:

```
public string AddEvent(DateTime date, int eventCount, int? eventId, string eventGuid){...}
```

My question is what does the question mark there do? My guess it has something to do with overloading since there's another overload method of `AddEvent` but I'm not sure...

Comment: there will be `!` soon

Comment: wrong duplicate added by mistake, how to remove it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple, this isn’t C++ code. It’s C#, where `?` denotes a [*nullable* value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). I.e. a value type that can also be `null`. `int?` is a shortcut for `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a simple type like int cannot be null, using ? allows the int to have a null value like an object.

Inside the function, you need to check to see if eventId is valid to use. You can do this by checking HasValue or equal to null. If you try to use it without checking, and it is null, then it will throw System.InvalidOperationException:

```
public string AddEvent(DateTime date, int eventCount, int? eventId, string eventGuid)
{
    // use HasValue
    if (eventId.HasValue)
        eventId++;

    // or check for null
    if (eventId != null)
        eventId++;
}
```